# How to make a div to being display when I clicked the link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

this is my code the problem is:
When I click the `Detail` link the `div` is open quickly and after that hide , I want to display not 
being hide.
all the thing is good the problem only in this statement:

```
echo "<td>"."  <a  href='computer.php?id=$record[id]' onClick='opendiv();'  >Detail</a> ".";
```

but if I changed above code to this way

```
echo "<td>"."  <a  href='#?id=$record[id]' onClick='opendiv();'  >Detail</a> "."'
```

the `div` is work good but in this time the `id` number not selected I want to select the `id` of the `detail` link so as to retrieving the information from the databse using the `id`

this is the javascript code:

```
function opendiv(){
document.getElementById("box").style.display="block"
}
function closediv(){
document.getElementById("box").style.display="none"
}
```

this is the css code:

```
#box{
display:none;
width:200px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
top:40px; 
}


<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<?php
//---------------connect to db ----------
include 'connect.php';

$sql="SELECT `id`, `name`, `student`, `teacher`, `year`, `level`, `abstract` FROM `computer` ";
$mydata=mysql_query($sql);

while($record=mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
include'generalvalue.php';
echo "<td>"."  <a  href='computer.php?id=$record[id]' onClick='opendiv();'  >Detail</a> "."</td>";
}//end while
?>
<div id="box"> 
<a href="#" onClick="closediv()" >Close</a><br><br>
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT  * FROM `computer` where id='$id'";
$mydata=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($mydata);
echo $row[6];
}//end if
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this question related to php

Comment: you can pass your id in your function as:- <?php echo "<td>"."  <a  href='#' onClick='opendiv(".$record[id].");'>Detail</a> "."</td>";
?>

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `<a>` tag when you click on "Detail". Browser is redirecting to **"computer.php"** in browser as per default tag behavior if you have not used jquery/java-script prevent default event.
You can use following :

```
echo "<td><a class='detail' href='#' data-id='" . $record['id'] . "'> Detail </a></td>";
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("a.detail").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        // make ajax call to "computer.php"
        $.ajax({
            "url": "computer.php",
            "data": {"id": id},
            "type": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "success": function(result) {
                if(result.status == "success"){
                    $("#yourDivID").html('').html(result.html);
                } else {
                    $("#yourDivID").html('').html(result.message);
                }
                //Show your div 
                $("#yourDivID").show();
            },
            "error": function(e) {}
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In your "computer.php" file you can use following code to handle ajax request

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']==='XMLHttpRequest' ) {
    if(isset($_POST['id']) && intval($_POST['id']) > 0 ){
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `computer` where id='$id'";
      $mydata = mysql_query($sql);
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($mydata);      
      echo json_encode(array("status" => "success", "html" => "<h3>".$row[6]."</h3>"));
      die();
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Please provide valid computer id to get detail."));
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the id in this statement <?php 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT  * FROM `computer` where id='$id'";
$mydata=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($mydata);
echo $row[6];
}//end if
?> I not want to call computer.php

Comment: You can use ajax call to use your code for getting data from "computer" table.

Comment: thanks bro but I don't understand well, can you write the adjax code for me because I am not good in javascript.